# CSS selector for director NodeJs

Tags: node.js, css-selectors

I am newbie at NodeJs and this is the first code I am trying. As for the CSS selector of the director I am stuck how to use CSS selector for it
This is the code and I am stuck at the line of variable director

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const URL = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8946378/?ref_=hm_fanfav_tt_2_pd_fp1';

(async () => {
    
    const response = await request(URL);
    let $ = cheerio.load(response);   
    let title = $('div[class="title_wrapper"] > h1').text();
    let rating = $('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').text();
    let director = $('h4:contains("Director:") a').text();
    console.log(title, rating, director);

})()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you install the `request` module? Because `request-promise` requires to install the `request` module.

Comment: No error. I didn't get the expected output for the Director which is `Rian Johnson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your director selector is not correct. Notice that h4 doesn't have an `a` tag. The `a` tag is a sibling of `h4`. Try this:

```
let director = $('h4:contains("Director:")').next("a").text();
```

Comment: How can I extract the href attribute? Forgive me as I am newbie in NodeJs. I tried `let director = $('h4:contains("Director:")').next("a").attr('href');` but this extarcts part of the href. I need the full link address.

Comment: I have never used cheerio before. Please check their documentation. But, I think the function is not `.href()` it is `.attr('href')`.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it displayed the href attribute .. but how can I get the full address? When I mouse over the href attribute I can see the full link address.

Comment: Just append it like this `const fullUrl = 'https://www.imdb.com' + director`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help Shihab.